# 4g icon always showing on my S6 (But my cellular network is not 4g)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, 4g

4g icon always shows on my top right side with signals bar on my newly bought(second hand) samsung S6 mobile. problem is that my cellular network is not 4G. It only supports 3G.

Is my S6 software fake or something ?

Answer (score 2):

Some countries/carriers, e.g. AT&T and T-Mobile call (DC-)HSPA+ "4G" (while HSPA+ is commonly referred to as "3.5G"), while they call real 4G "4G LTE" or simply "LTE". Using phones or such carrier origin with a HSPA+-capable SIM will display "4G".